# How to get value from json with random ID

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, decode

I have a problem with retrieving values from JSON

I do not know how to retrieve a value [NAME] that is given after id (which is random)

```
    "allplayers": {
    "76561197979570214": {
        "clan": "FBÏ",
        "name": "phr",
        "observer_slot": 6,
        "team": "T",
    },
    "76561198156373160": {
        "clan": "ZOWIE",
        "name": "TOAO",
        "observer_slot": 7,
        "team": "T",
    },
    "76561198071702537": {
        "clan": "Team Biceps",
        "name": "snatchie",
        "observer_slot": 8,
        "team": "T",
    },
},
```

With constant values

```
"map": {
    "mode": "competitive",
    "name": "de_overpass",
    "phase": "live",
    "round": 7,
    "team_ct": {
        "score": 7,
        "name": "Team Kinguin",
        "flag": "PL",
        "timeouts_remaining": 1,
        "matches_won_this_series": 0
    },
    "team_t": {
        "score": 0,
        "name": "Samsung4Gamers",
        "flag": "PL",
        "timeouts_remaining": 1,
        "matches_won_this_series": 0
    },
    "num_matches_to_win_series": 0,
    "current_spectators": 3,
    "souvenirs_last_round": 0,
    "souvenirs_total": 0
},
```

Im using

```
data = JSON.parse(msg);
$("#ct_score").text(data.map.team_ct.score);
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Will this key always have **team** word attached to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through you result object's properties and check if the current propertie is it's own, like this :

```js
   allplayers = {
    "76561197979570214": {
        "clan": "FBÏ",
        "name": "phr",
        "observer_slot": 6,
        "team": "T",
    },
    "76561198156373160": {
        "clan": "ZOWIE",
        "name": "TOAO",
        "observer_slot": 7,
        "team": "T",
    },
    "76561198071702537": {
        "clan": "Team Biceps",
        "name": "snatchie",
        "observer_slot": 8,
        "team": "T",
    },
};

for(var key in allplayers){
    if(allplayers.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        if(allplayers[key].hasOwnProperty('name')){
          console.log(allplayers[key].name);
        }  
    }
}
```